# Matching partial text to array elements

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to slice string value of the current counter to do a partial match, is there a better way to match partial text to various array elements

```
var autoList = [];

for (i = 0; i <= lang.length; i++) {

        if (entered.value === lang[i].slice(0, entered.value.length)) {
            autoList.push(lang[i]);
        }

    };
```

Comment: Start with `var autoList = lang.filter(...`.

Comment: Are you trying to determine if `entered.value` is within `lang[i]`?